# substr invalid in an echo clause?

Tags: php

what about this statement below would simply cause no output ? Is this an invalid way to do a substr?

```
<p><?php if(!empty($results->lname)){echo substr($result->lname, 0, 1); }else{echo "<br>";} ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 things that could cause an issue in :

```
<?PHP 
if (!empty($results->lname))
{
    echo substr($result->lname, 0, 1);
}
else
{
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

1. The object in the condition is `$results` while in the echo is `$result`.
2. The string is not a string and could cause some issues. Try to var dump the objec